# Reading in .csv file to R. Error in Scan

Tags: r, csv

Reading in a .csv file, but got the following error:

```
Books <- read.table(file.choose(),header=TRUE,sep=";")
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
line 21688 did not have 3 elements
```

.csv file name BX-Book-Ratings.csv

Original - 1 column and 1048576 rows

Shown - 1 column and 10 rows

```
User-ID;"ISBN";"Book-Rating"        
276725;"034545104X";"0"     
276726;"0155061224";"5"     
276727;"0446520802";"0"     
276729;"052165615X";"3"     
276729;"0521795028";"6"     
276733;"2080674722";"0"     
276736;"3257224281";"8"     
276737;"0600570967";"6"     
276744;"038550120X";"7"
```

Area with the error - rows 21687:21694

4376;"0345378490";"0"
4376;"38208715X";"5"
 4377;"\"0210000010";"8"
4385;"0061042331";"0"
4385;"0061083402";"10"
4385;"0061083577";"0"
4385;"0061093343";"9"
4385;"0061096156";"10"

Please let me know if I can provide additional information. Thank you.

Comment: What happens on row 21688?

Comment: So what's preventing you from opening the file in a text editor and going to line 21688 (or near there)?

Comment: Better to see what happens in the corrupted line but You can also red setting `fill=TRUE` in `read.table`

Comment: One of two problems is likely: either a "#" character or a mismatched quote. First thing to try would be adding `..., comment.char=TRUE` to your argument list.

Comment: open a bash terminal and have a look at line 21688 for the funny character:   

    `head -21690 file.csv | tail -3`

Comment: @Justin, thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to post that row. After taking out the X and /, the Books dataset did not separate. R displays the dataset as 1048575 obs. of 1 variable. Should the sep=";" command separate the data into three variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have sufficient reputation points to add this as a comment above. Are you certain you counted correctly in pasting rows 21687:21694? The error was supposed to be in line 21688, but the line below has mismatched quotes... Data cleaning is a major step in such analyses.

4377;"\"0210000010";"8"

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My intention for pasting extra rows involve showing the data around the mismatched quotes. Removing the "X" and "/" fixed the error.